# Spark Exception in windows: java.io.IOException: fail to rename shuffle file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am facing an issue when trying to run a piece of Spark Streaming code. I am trying to read data from a kafka topic and then pushing the processed data to elastic search. I am running this code in eclipse on windows and have configured Kafka, Spark, zookeeper and elasticsearch. I am getting the following error:

```
  18/02/20 14:52:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 5)
  java.io.IOException: fail to rename file C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-cb45497b-7f85-4158-815b-852edecbb2c5\0f\shuffle_1_0_0.index.ca3b55d2-6c26-4798-a17b-21a42f099126 to C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-cb45497b-7f85-4158-815b-852edecbb2c5\0f\shuffle_1_0_0.index
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  18/02/20 14:52:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 5, localhost): java.io.IOException: fail to rename file C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-cb45497b-7f85-4158-815b-852edecbb2c5\0f\shuffle_1_0_0.index.ca3b55d2-6c26-4798-a17b-21a42f099126 to C:\Users\shash\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-cb45497b-7f85-4158-815b-852edecbb2c5\0f\shuffle_1_0_0.index
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can someone give me some inputs on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem by setting spark.local.dir to another path which you have rename permission.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.local.dir","another path");
```

I am new in spark, hope it works to you.